# How to make iCloud 3.0 on Windows sync bookmarks with Safari

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, safari, bookmarks

Since updating to iCloud 3.0 on Windows 7, I've noticed that my Windows installation of Safari is no longer syncing my iPad bookmarks.

Looking at the settings in iCloud, Safari is no longer included:

[image: screenshot of Bookmarks Options dialog]

As with my previous, much older question - [How to make iCloud on Windows sync bookmarks with Safari, not Internet Explorer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/how-to-make-icloud-on-windows-sync-bookmarks-with-safari-not-internet-explorer) - I don't want to mix up the bookmarks of my desktop browsers with those on my mobile devices.

Has Apple really removed the ability to sync bookmarks with PC Safari, or am I missing some trick?

Comment: Someone else reporting the same thing: [Farewell Windows Safari, as Apple excludes its homegrown browser from iCloud bookmark sync](http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/19/farewell-windows-safari-as-apple-excludes-from-icloud-bookmark-sync/), on September 19, 2013

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing when I found this:

http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/19/farewell-windows-safari-as-apple-excludes-from-icloud-bookmark-sync/

I looks like this is no longer possible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I see that's the same page that I linked to in the comment on the question.